# Saving output from parsing json file and passing it to Bigqueryinsertjoboperator

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I need some advise on solving this requirement for auditing purpose . I am using airflow composer - dataflow java operator job which spits out json file after job completion with status and error message details (into airflow data folder ) . I want to extract the status and error message from json file via some operator and then pass the variable to next pipeline job  Bigqueryinsertjoboperator which calls the stored proc and passes status and error message as input parameter and finally gets written into BQ dataset table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to do XCom and JINJA templating. When you return meta-data from the operator, the data is stored in XCom and you can retrieve it using JINJA templating or Python code in Python operator (or Python code in your custom operator).

Those are two  very good articles from Marc Lamberti (who also has really nice courses on Airlfow) describing how templating and jinja can be leveraged in Airflow https://marclamberti.com/blog/templates-macros-apache-airflow/ and this one describes XCom: https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-xcom/

By combining the two you can get what you want.